# What's the meaning of "you were ages"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, idioms

In the movie Allied, Marianne says to Max, who just arrived home, "You were ages."

What does this mean?

The Cambridge Dictionary says that [ages](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ages) means a very long time, like in 
*It’s been ages since I’ve seen you.*

but is "you were ages" grammatical? Is it a common idiomatic expression?

Comment: It means they took a long time.

Comment: retracted downvote but the "original post" is now asking a different question.

Comment: *"You were ages"* has the same meaning as *"You were/took a long time"*. It is perfectly grammatical and idiomatic in BrEnglish. Can you explain why you think it might not be?

Comment: I've never heard this idiom before, so I am also curious where people say this and where it came from. Is the pattern productive or is it a fixed idiom?

Comment: The context in't clear. Was the sentence simply a complete "You were ages." or did something follow or what? Can you give the full sentence before and after, enough for context?

Comment: The poor context makes reliable translation a problem.  But probably it means "You took a long time."

Answer (score 3):

Generally "you were ages" means "what you were doing took a long time".

Answer (score 1):

***[Ages](http://www.theidioms.com/ages/)*** is often used with a different set of prepositions and word combinations to suggest that something or someone has required too much time, or that too much time has passed or will be passed.

Most common usages are:

> for ages,
> in ages,
> takes ages,
> it will be ages,
> you were ages,
> it was ages,
> ages before,
> after ages.

Example sentences:

> - I haven’t seen you ***in ages*** – you look different.
> - We haven’t been here ***for ages***; we must come here more often.
> - ***It takes ages*** to learn to play the guitar.
> - ***It took ages*** to get there.
> - ***It will be ages*** before we get our exam results.
> - I will not be able to meet her ***for ages*** because I have so much work on.
> - ***You were ages*** in the bathroom. What were you doing?
> - ***I was ages*** putting this proposal together. I hope they like it.
> - I met her online about 2010, but ***it was ages*** before I met her in real life.
> - The restaurant was lovely and the conversation was good, but ***it was ages***  before they brought the food.
> - I have not seen her going to temple ***in ages***.

(theidioms.com)

Comment: Answers to off-topic questions should be left to inexperienced and new users who might want to build up easy rep. But this is not your case, despite the 6K rep you have today, you once had 145K or thereabouts, so you know the "rules of etiquette"

Comment: @Mari-LouA - there is more than rep going on on ELU. This question is interesting, at least to NNS eyes, and it is worth a full answer. It should probably be moved to ELL, but still worth an answer. BTW, what dictionary explains what "you were ages" mean? and the set of variants of different  usages in which ages can be used?

Comment: Where did you get your answer? From Googling.

Comment: @Mari-LouA yes, not from dictionaries.

Comment: It took me maybe five seconds to find its meaning in Oxford Dictionaries https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/age

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I cant find the specific expression in question...

Comment: `2.2 ages/an age British informal A very long time.
‘I haven't seen her for ages’` >‘I promise I won't write about television for ages.’ and > ‘Finally after what seemed like ages we had our drinks and were sitting outside.’ and > ‘The infirm and ill were beamed to safe havens ages ago.’

Comment: @Mari-LouA - yes...the sentence which is not clear is ***"you were ages"***, see the update.

Comment: Oh look, your comments are upvoted and so is your answer. Not by me, they aren't.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - nor did the OP

Comment: @Mari-LouA I found the question interesting. "For ages" (despite being marked as British) is used in AmE (my dialect). However, the definition does not mention the expression "you were ages", which is not used in AmE. I understand that the grammaticality is obvious to you, but it is not so for people who speak other dialects, not even with that dictionary definition.

Comment: @Laurel did user15969 "explain" the usage, the grammar, and why it is acceptable. Is it only an idiom? The original question asked about the "meaning" of the term, not "why" or "how" or "if" it was grammatical. I retracted my downvote, but my close vote remains.

Comment: @Laurel - thanks, not to mention NNS difficulties with expressions like that!!

Comment: @Mari-LouA - no they didnt, another more detailed answer is wanted. I read on Meta ,not long ago, about someone complaining that too many potentially good questions are CVed too quickly. Did I misread?